# Segmentation fault DPDK

Tags: c++, dpdk

I've written a sender application using dpdk libraries.

```
struct my_message{
    struct rte_ether_hdr eth_hdr; // the ethernet header
    char payload[10];
};

*/ Sender Application */
void my_send(struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool, uint16_t port, uint64_t max_packets)
{
    int retval;
    struct rte_mbuf *bufs[BURST_SIZE];
    struct rte_ether_addr src_mac_addr;
    retval = rte_eth_macaddr_get(0, &src_mac_addr); // gets MAC address of Port 0
    struct rte_ether_addr dst_mac_addr = {{0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0xff}}; 
    struct my_message *my_pkt;

    int j=0;
    uint16_t sent_packets = BURST_SIZE; //BURST_SIZE is 256
    do{
        for(int i = 0; i < sent_packets; i ++)
        {
            bufs[i] = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(mbuf_pool); //allocates a new mbuff from mempool
            my_pkt = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(bufs[i], struct my_message*); //points (pointer is casted to struct my_message*) to start of data in mbuf
            *my_pkt->payload = 'Hello2021';    
            int pkt_size = sizeof(struct my_message);
            bufs[i]->pkt_len = bufs[i]->data_len = pkt_size;
            rte_ether_addr_copy(&src_mac_addr, &my_pkt->eth_hdr.s_addr);
            rte_ether_addr_copy(&dst_mac_addr, &my_pkt->eth_hdr.d_addr);
            my_pkt->eth_hdr.ether_type = htons(PTP_PROTOCOL);
        }

        const uint16_t sent_packets = rte_eth_tx_burst(port, 0, bufs, BURST_SIZE);
        printf("Number of packets tx %" PRIu16 "\n", sent_packets);

        j = j + sent_packets;
    }
    while(j < max_packets);
        /* Free any unsent packets. */
    if (unlikely(sent_packets < BURST_SIZE)) {
            uint16_t buf;
            for (buf = sent_packets; buf < BURST_SIZE; buf++)
                    rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs[buf]);
        }        

}
```

I call this function as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
-- 
EAL initialization and port initialization
--
struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool;
my_send(mbuf_pool, 0, 3000000);
```

The program compiles with no errors, however, upon running this program, I'm getting a segmentation fault. Following is the output:

[image]

I ran gdb but couldn't debug from the gdb output

and got the following message

Thread 1 "app_tx_v2" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555567 in my_send ()

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and replace the picture with the output as text. From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: @stackinside, thanks for the hint. You are indeed right that `rte_pktmbuf_alloc()` returns a NULL pointer. The next step is to understand why is this happening. and how to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the provided source code and debug printouts, every time `rte_eth_tx_burst()` fails to send the whole batch of 256 mbufs, your program leaks unsent packets. The loop reiterates thus overwriting `mbufs`. The leak subsequently grows, and the mempool runs out of available objects. At some point `rte_pktmbuf_alloc()` returns `NULL`. Your program does not check the return value and thus the subsequent access to the mbuf data causes the observed segmentation fault.

As for debug information, I trust you already know that one needs to specify `-g` argument on `gcc` invocation in order to have it. Also, please make sure to specify `-Wall` key.

As for the program itself, it's hard to read and thus it hides the said mbuf leak. Consider re-implementing it the following way:

```
static void
fill_out_mbuf(struct rte_mbuf *m) {
    /* Get mtod */
    /* Set the data / packet size */
    /* Fill out the header and payload */
    /* ... */
}

static uint16_t
send_mbufs(uint16_t          port,
           struct rte_mbuf **mbufs,
           uint16_t          nb)
{
    uint16_t ret;

    ret = rte_eth_tx_prepare(port, 0, mbufs, nb);
    if (ret == 0)
        return 0;

    return rte_eth_tx_burst(port, 0, mbufs, ret);
}

#define NB_RETRIES_MAX (1000)

static void
my_send(struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool,
        uint16_t            port,
        uint64_t            max_packets)
{
    struct rte_mbuf *mbufs[BURST_SIZE];
    unsigned int     nb_retries;
    uint16_t         nb_mbufs;
    uint16_t         nb_done;
    uint16_t         i;

    if (max_packets == 0)
        return;

    do {
        memset(mbufs, 0, sizeof(mbufs));

        nb_mbufs = RTE_MIN(max_packets, RTE_DIM(mbufs));
        nb_retries = 0;
        nb_done = 0;

        if (rte_pktmbuf_alloc_bulk(mbuf_pool, mbufs, nb_mbufs) != 0)
            break;

        for (i = 0; i < nb_mbufs; ++i)
            fill_out_mbuf(mbufs[i]);

        do {
            nb_done += send_mbufs(port, mbufs + nb_done, nb_mbufs - nb_done);
            ++nb_retries;
        } while (nb_done < nb_mbufs && nb_retries < NB_RETRIES_MAX);

        max_packets -= nb_done;
    } while (max_packets > 0 && nb_retries < NB_RETRIES_MAX);

    for (i = nb_done; i < nb_mbufs; ++i)
        rte_pktmbuf_free(mbufs[i]);
}
```

The key points here are as follows:

1. Factor out functions like `fill_out_mbuf()` for the sake of code clarity;
2. Invoke `rte_eth_tx_prepare()` before `rte_eth_tx_burst()` as required by the RTE API contract;
3. Use `rte_pktmbuf_alloc_bulk()` for improved efficacy;
4. If the mbuf batch has been sent only partially, don't start from scratch; instead, attempt to send remaining mbufs;
5. Do not retry sending infinitely; limit the number of retries.